# Can't see collections in VS2022 debugger in Blazor

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm debugging a BlazorWASM application in VS2022 - all works well except if I place a breakpoint in the code.

The Autos window will populate with the local variables (including collections) but when I attempt to drill into a collection (a list in my case) I merely see 'Capacity' and 'Count' and no details of the items in the list itself.

[image: List with no details of items]

I think this only started with VS2022 - v17.4.

Not sure what I'm missing here.  More detail:

Runtime: .net 7.0.0
Nuget packages:  all v7.0.0

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19942, I've experienced this issue as well,
"that case related to having one version of nuget package and another version of the runtime."

Comment: I'm aligned - so unfortunately I don't this explains it.